# display the avg salary and loc of each location

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, scalar-subquery

Write a query to display the LOC and average salary of Each location.(Scalar Sub query).
LOC is in dept table and salary is in emp table.
I have to do this with scalar subquery.

```
select loc,(select avg(sal) from emp) 
from dept group by loc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below query. You have to join emp and dept table and fetch the results.

Using join:

```
select d.loc, avg(e.sal) from emp e
inner join dept d
on (e.dept_id = d.dept_id)   -- Changed the column it the foreign key is something else
group by d.loc;
```

Using sub query:

```
select d.loc, (select avg(sal) from emp e where d.dept_id = e.dept_id)
from dept d group by d.loc;
```

[image]

Comment: your answer is perfectly correct and it will fetch the correct rows but i have to do this with scalar subquery. so, can you help me out.

Comment: Provided you using subquery as well

Comment: no it says ( ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression")

Comment: It should work, i have added working screenshot as well. Which version of oracle are you using?

Comment: May be alias issue, have edited the query. Please try now

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to use scalar subquery then you can use below.

Note: if you need to use `GROUP BY` you have to use `DISTINCT` in your  `SELECT` instead.

```
  WITH DEPT
     AS (SELECT 'TR' AS LOC, 1 DEPTID FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'FR' AS LOC, 2 DEPTID FROM DUAL),
     EMP
     AS (SELECT 15 AS SAL, 1 DEPTID FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 20 AS SAL, 2 DEPTID FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 35 AS SAL, 1 DEPTID FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 45 AS SAL, 2 DEPTID FROM DUAL
         )
  SELECT D.LOC,
         (SELECT AVG(SAL)
            FROM EMP E
           WHERE D.DEPTID = E.DEPTID)
    FROM DEPT D
```

Comment: its says (ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression").i don't know what's wrong in it.

Comment: Edited my answer please try this again. It was because of group by statement. @MAYANKRAJ

Comment: I have been using 11g too trust me. @MAYANKRAJ

Answer (score 0):

It is not needed to group by loc at the end of the query

```
select loc,
(select avg(sal) from emp 
where emp.deptno = dept.deptno) avg_sal
from dept;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3q28.png